# Shell script to enter Docker container and execute command, and eventually exit

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I want to write a shell script that enters into a running docker container, edits a specific file and then exits it.

My initial attempt was this -

1. Create run.sh file.
2. Paste the following commands into it

   ```
   docker exec -it container1 bash
   sed -i -e 's/false/true/g' /opt/data_dir/gs.xml
   exit
   ```
3. Run the script -

   ```
   bash ./run.sh
   ```

However, once the script enters into the container1 it lands to the bash terminal of it. Seems like the whole script breaks as soon as I enter into the container, leaving parent container behind which contains the script.

Comment: When/why do you want to do this?  Does your image actually need a custom entry point script that can update config files at startup time based on environment variables or other settings?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved By using the below piece of code

```
myHostName="$(hostname)"
docker exec -i -e VAR=${myHostName} root_reverse-proxy_1 bash <<'EOF'
sed -i -e "s/ServerName .*/ServerName $VAR/" /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
echo -e "\n Updated /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf $VAR \n"
exit
```

Comment: here `root_reverse-proxy_1` is the name of the docker image

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close. You can try something like:

```
docker exec container1 sed -i -e 's/false/true/g' /opt/data_dir/gs.xml
```

Explanations:

- `-it` is for interactive session, so you don't need it here.
- docker can execute any command (like `sed`). You don't have to run `sed` via bash

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error : OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"sed\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: Is sed installed in the image? Use the full path like "/usr/bin/sed"

Comment: Ahh!! May be that's the issue. Sed is not installed. Unfortunately, I'm pulling the docker image from somewhere else and therefore won't be able to pre-install it, or install it through shell (may be!). But I get the clue.

Comment: Similar things for easy in place replacement: awk and perl. (maybe one of them is installed...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will look into it :)